# How to retrieve all the tweets of my followers through the twitter streaming API with twitter4J?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm using the following Code with the twitter4J library to retrieve all tweets of my followers:

```
friendsIDs = TwitterConnectionManager.getTwitter().getFriendsIDs().getIDs();
twitterStream = twitterStreamFactory.getOAuthAuthorizedInstance(getTwitterAccessToken());
twitterStream.filter(new FilterQuery(friendIDs));
```

This provides me with all tweets that are from one of my friends but also tweets that contain @username of one of my friends. If I'm following an account like Twitter I get all Tweets containing @Twitter. I'm filtering this tweets after they arrive but they create a lot of unneeded data and CPU usage and since I use this code on a mobile device I would like to create a filter that gives me only the tweets that appear in my timeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.  Take a look at the docs for the filter endpoint here:

http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/filter

Maybe you could put an app-server between your mobile apps and the twitter api that does the filtering?